# Bootstrap 3 - 100% height div inside div inside column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Slightly different from the other posts I have found as this is a nested div.
I have 3 columns with a blue background, nested as below.  The nesting is important for the layout padding in my design.

As it stands the background/ div won't go to 100% full height.
I've tried a few different things (display:table and display:table-cell) found in other posts, but becuase the blue backround is on the inner div, this won't stretch. I cannot move the bluepanel to the parent because the padding then disappears.

Here is the code I need to work.

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid red">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 panelblue">
        some text col 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 panelblue">
        some text col 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 panelblue">
        some text col 3
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/M4fw8dYcsI

Comment: full-height of what ? window ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Currently we cannot replicate the issue with the provided code.

Comment: Look at bootply example - its not duplicate if you read it properly.